# Power series expansion of associated legendre polynomial.

Tags: derivatives, power-series, orthogonal-polynomials, legendre-polynomials

What is the power series expansion of the associated legendre polynomial given by $P_l^m(z)$ ? what is the derivative of this function with respect to z.?

Comment: The associated Legendre polynomials have a hypergeometric expression (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_Legendre_polynomials#Generalization_via_hypergeometric_functions). It might be possible to derive the power series from this characterization. An other way to derive the power series might be to use Frobenius method (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Noud Would you mind telling me about the derivative of this function with respect to z.?